# Jump to suggested edits

Tags: google-docs

I received some suggestions how to improve my document:

[image: edit suggestions]

I was able to find one, but not the other two. Clicking the timestamp has no effect.

How can I jump to a suggested edit in order to review it?

Comment: Check this [using suggested edits in doc](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2456460/google-docs-3-incredibly-useful-tools-for-edits-and-revisions.html) whether this helps.

Comment: @Vembu the article doesn't describe how to jump to edit from the comment list.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking Comments in the Google Docs Comment History will jump to the location of the text which was marked via the comment or suggestion.
If the jumping does not occur when clicking on the entry, it means that all initial text that the comment/suggestion was on, got deleted.

I have this happen a lot to my comments, and have yet to find a way to fix it with Google Docs. This means once text got deleted it is not possible to make the comments jump again - unless you use the Doc Version History to revert it to an earlier non-deleted version. [see this Google Support Article about File Versions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843)

As a workaround I ask all collaborators to not delete text. Instead they have to strike-through text they want to have removed.
Another option is to make an empty space within the marked text (so it counts as part of the marked text) and only then delete the rest of the text. This way, the comment/suggestion can still be jumping to the right location. I can create an example doc showcasing how we do that in case this would help you.